# keyboard open change the view in phone

Tags: html, css

I am building an app for mobile in html.

I have created a form and my problem is that when the user open the keyboard it make the height of the screen very small and all the form destroyed.

My solution for this is when the user open the keyboard I want to hide the title and then all the form will be on place. But my problem is how to know that?

Or how can I make CSS only for devices with height less then X.

Thanks

Comment: You could listen to the `focus` event of your input, or use css `@media (max-height: 300px) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries are there for you.
Basically they allow you to test some properties of your 'client' (like width, height, media type... and so on) and apply the proper css classes and rules.

Here's an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Hope it helps.